# Similarities and Differences Between CE Series Clearomizers?

Tags: series

Similarities and Differences Between CE Series. I want answer in  brief discussion to complete understand.

Answer (score 0):

CE series clearomizers are all top coil clearomizers and can compatible with ego batteries. CE4 is non-rebuildable but others are all rebuildable and removable. CE4 and CE5 have only 1.6 volume capacity. CE6 is usually called vivi nova which has 3 ml volume capacity and have outer thread. CE7 is mini vivi nova and also have outer thread which can compatible with 510 thread battery. For more information, please check: http://youtu.be/zI6Ihq-ipT8